# login-database - alternative to BugMeNot(.com)?

Tags: web-services, login

a long time ago [BugMeNot.com](http://bugmenot.com/) was really good and with its [browser-addon (at least for firefox)](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/bugmenot/) awesome, but now - i assume because of it's popularity and therefore too much removal requests - it is unfortunately nearly useless.

are there good alternatives to BugMeNot which work on more sites?
--> i'm aware that this can't be guaranteed because obviously BugMeNot doesn't publish any statistic... so let's say: are there alternatives which don't accept removals or at least handle them very strict?

well... a browser-addon would be a killer-feature but (after i stopped dreaming) it is not required.

---

**for those who don't know what BugMeNot is:**

- it is a website/webservice (or more or less a "simple" database) with logins for websites which bothers you with free registration
- user can contribute their (fake-)logins
- additional a browser-addon is provided to avoid the annoying copy&paste (especially if some logins aren't working - it gets quickly tedious)

Answer (score 1):

the only alternatives i found are

- [<s>LoginFinder</s>](http://www.loginfinder.com/) and
- [Login 2](http://login2.me/)

but on the sites i tested them, all 3 (including [BugMeNot](http://bugmenot.com/)) does not work.